# Excel IF statement not returning expected result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on a formula in excel, it seems simple and yet I am struggling.
`=IF(AND(P2="TRUE",S2="TRUE","CANCEL")`

So, what this does is, it compares column P and S which have text in them, either PUSH or CANCEL....so, if both are TRUE I expect the result to be PUSH(in column Q) and if one of the two(P2 or S2) is FALSE to return CANCEL(in column Q).
But, it is not doing that. It always returns CANCEL.
However, if column P and S have 0's and 1's in the cells, it works just fine.
Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

This is all in excel...I even tried ChatGPT but no luck. I tried having the FALSE cells be blank, and that worked. But why not with text????

Comment: If column P and S have either PUSH or CANCEL in them, why are you using `"TRUE"`?

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up the IF syntax and AND syntax. You need to close the parenthesis of your AND statement, before continuing the IF statement like so:

`=IF(AND(P2="TRUE",S2="TRUE"),"CANCEL")`

However, this won't work unless you're checking if both P2 & S2 have "True" as their cell value, which based on your question is not how your sheet is structured.

I believe you want it to read:

`=IF(AND(P2="PUSH",S2="PUSH"),"PUSH","CANCEL")`

This will check if P2 and S2 both say "PUSH" and if they both do, the cell this formula is in will return "PUSH" otherwise it will say cancel if either or both  P2 & S2 have any other value in their cells.